# Multiple Datatables Form Update vs Individual Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a view in ASP.NET MVC which contains multiple jQuery Datatables. Currently each table submits it's own ajax request on Add/Update/Delete which queries the database. I'm wondering if that is the ideal way to do it, or should all the data be submitted through a form once the user is done manipulating each table.

Answer (score 0):

Most sites do it with a form.

But I think using ajax is also good, because the call to the server is asynchronous and so it doesn't delay your page. Since the user cannot change fields in very high speed, it should not be an issue to keep as it is.